# Why my VF behaves differently as a public page

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting

I have a VF page which is basically html with js.
For historical reasons I use JS remoting to push the values from the form to the controller.

I have 44 fields so I cannot use one method and so I use two, one creates a record with some fields and the second updates the same records with the remaining fields.

To make a long story short, everything works fine when I test it internally e.g. cs17.salesforce.com/MySurvey?ref=xxxxxxxxxxx
When I test the same as a public VF page e.g. vm.force.com/MySurvey?ref=xxxxxxxxxxx only the fist JS remoting is executed, the second one is never called.

I cannot understand why...

This is a snippet of my JS code:

```
if(ok){
  console.log("form ok");
  createObj();                   
  return false;
}
else{
     console.log("form not ok");
     goToByScroll(lowestFieldID);                    
     return false;
}

function createObj(){              
   try{            
  saveSurvey1();                   
   }
   catch(err){
     console.log(err);
     alert(err);
 return false;                  
   }
}
```

This is the handleResult method which is used by both methods:

```
    function handleResult(result, event){

       if(event.status){                                           

           if(jsRemotingCall == 1){
                console.log("new Survey created with id " + result);
                saveSurvey2(result);
                return false;
           }
           if(jsRemotingCall == 2){
                console.log("Survey updated with id " + result);
                top.location="http://www.facebook.com";                     
                return true;
            }                       
            return false;                           
        } 
        else if(event.type == 'exception'){
           alert(event.type);
           console.log("failed to create survey " + event.message); 
           //javascript remoting was not called
           return false;                                               
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the debug logs for the site guest user?

Comment: Yes, this is how I see that one JS remoting is being executed and the 2nd is not

Comment: Are you able to post a bit more of your code so that I can investigate deeper?